# How to send dashboard as pdf which consist of svg and large table in java?

Tags: java, javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to send report as pdf which consist of fusion charts and table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export individual charts from your dashboard as PDF, FusionCharts has the export feature. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-interactivity-exporting-as-image-and-pdf-introduction.html)

Or if you want to export the entire dashboard as PDF / image, you can use the solution from one of the FusionChart's dashboards [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dashboards/twitter/)

In this dashboard, you can search for a hashtag and it loads results with text, chart, images and if you click on share, it will generate a screenshot of entire page ( in your case you need this as PDF ). You can download the source code and configure it to your need.

Let me know if this helps